# XNA: My richtextbox is invisible when fullscreen is toggled

Tags: c#, textbox, xna, richtextbox, fullscreen

I have added a richtextbox in XNA but it is invisible when fullscreen is toggled

This is my code:

```
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    public Engine()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        this.IsMouseVisible = false;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
        richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";

        richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle).Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
    }
```

The code above is working fine if graphics.IsFullScren is set to false

Comment: Is `Window.Handle` still valid when you don't have a "window"?

Comment: You should debug if `Controls.Add(richTextBox1)` is actually adding your `richTextBox` in that case.

Comment: The code is adding the richtextbox when fullscreen is on but it is still not visible.
richtextbox.visible or .show() doesn't help either.

Also, if i move the mouse on the "invisible richtextbox" i can see how the cursor changes as it usually does when you move the mouse on a text.

Comment: Hmm... I guess this is the only way:             graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(Window.Handle).WorkingArea.Height;
            Window.AllowUserResizing = true;

Comment: you could try setting the Windows TopMost property to true

Answer (score 0):

When you set Direct X to run full screen, your form is no longer visible. when you form is not visible, your controls are not visible.

You are better of implementing your own UI for a textbox. A bit of work, but not as bad as it may seem...